# Making a scroll-able text field in html?

Tags: html

[image: What i'm getting]

Is it anyhow possible that I can view all the contents of the text input here?
All these values are coming from database.

I used `style="overflow-x:auto"` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrapping the inputs in a container and limit it's width and then use overflow property on the container instead of the inputs:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;/*for example only*/
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;/*for example only*/
  padding: 10px;/*for example only*/
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" value="687sjkfkjahfkgjahskjdghaskhkjhasdkjghasjkhgkjsadhgkjsdkjfhskdhfkjsa">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="687sjkfkjahfkgjahskjdghaskhkjhasdkjghasjkhgkjsadhgkjsdkjfhskdhfkjsa">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="687sjkfkjahfkgjahskjdghaskhkjhasdkjghasjkhgkjsadhgkjsdkjfhskdhfkjsa">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="687sjkfkjahfkgjahskjdghaskhkjhasdkjghasjkhgkjsadhgkjsdkjfhskdhfkjsa">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="text" value="687sjkfkjahfkgjahskjdghaskhkjhasdkjghasjkhgkjsadhgkjsdkjfhskdhfkjsa">
</div>
```